# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3 in IE 11 while trying to upload an excel

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

While uploading an excel with more than some amount of records (excel with less number of records works fine) in IE 11 throws the following error in console and aborts the request.

```
    Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3 
    SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.
```

I'm using the following code to upload the excel,

```
       function uploadFile(url, file, config) {
        var fdata = new FormData();
        fdata.append('file', file);
        var promise = $http({
            url: webRoot(url),
            method: 'POST',
            data: fdata,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        });
```

I'm making a GET request before attempting subsequent POST request in order to avoid security certificate issue.

Any one please guide me to sort out this error..

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. It was caused due to the unavailability of OCSP server of certificate. Once it was reachable, everything started working. Unavailability of OCSP server causes issue only for IE. Other (modern) browsers probably ignore this. There are code snippets available on internet on how to deal with issue using $.ajax but I am yet to find a solution using angularjs $http service.